# Show Notification at particular time with AlarmManager

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-alarms

I need to display a notification daily at particular time (for example: 4.25PM). I am using `AlarmManager` and `Notification`. I set the alarm on landing page of the application. I also have implemented the `BroadcastReceiver` for it.

Code to set the alarm:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 16);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 25);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Intent notificationmassage = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Notificationmassage.class);

//This is alarm manager
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0 , notificationmassage, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

This is the broadcast receiver

```
public class Notificationmassage extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        Log.i("notification", "visible");

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, Notificationmassage.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("xyz")
                .setContentText("It will contain dummy content");
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }  
}
```

What is wrong with this approach?

Comment: Hi. Whats the question... Sorry scrolled Down. Well the only thing i can see that might cause a problem is what happens if the guy does not open the application.

Comment: Hey I need to send notification throw android app at particular time, I have done above code but it's not working..

Comment: hi. Define not working. Is it not getting to the broadcast or is it not displaying notification

Comment: have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>`
and `<receiver  android:process=":remote" android:name="Alarm"></receiver>` ?

Comment: I am new in android.. I have not tried much.. But it is not going in brodcast reciver, that's what i understand since it is not showing notification

Comment: Hi. Why you setting the pendingintent to the "Notificationmassage.class" that's the Broadcastreceiver not the activity.

Comment: No not in android manifest file..btw can i test it on android emulator or i need android cell compulsory for alarm manager like geolocation

Comment: Pintac but i have added notification code in brodcast reciver.. is that wrong ?

Comment: Use [`PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29) instead. Also, you can just test it on the emulator.

Comment: Hi. Add "android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger()"  to the top of "onReceive" function and debug it and see if it gets there. U use this to make it wait for the debugger need to use it for stuff like serviceintent and sometimes broadcastreceivers.Just remove if you run normally again.

Comment: Your alarmmanager is calling your broadcastreceiver. So the notification you create in the broadcastreceiver need to go somewhere when you click it like an activity that's what the pendingintent in the broadcast receiver is for.

Comment: Thanks Will check give me some time..

Comment: Nice example http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-broadcast-receiver-notification-tutorial/

Answer (score 4):

Add reciever to Manifest.xml if you don't do this before.

```
 <receiver android:name="org.yourapp.Notificationmassage"></receiver>
```

in application section

```
    <application>
       ....

       <receiver android:name="org.yourapp.Notificationmassage"></receiver>

    </application>
```

If you already do that, please edit your question and show your Manifest.xml