# Calling notification on set time

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I have a notification in my code, but I want it to be activated when the device reaches a certain time. For example: 
5:00pm > Notification is called
Any idea how this can be done? Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: In local timezone? or UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this sample.

[On Github](https://github.com/TinasheMzondiwa/sample-alarm-manager)

Comment: Please add the code in your answer.  Link only answers are considered to be no answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check this Question
[Show Notification at particular time with AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26037211/3480938)

P.S.: Sry cannot add this as a comment because of the lack of *reputation points*.